# moadmin fails to find mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb

moadmin.php reports it can't access mongodb and that I must install the mongo extension for php. Moadmin version is 1.1.5 and github reports the latest edit was in 2017. The extension was installed on my ubuntu 18.04 lts server as instructed in php.net with the command:

```
pecl install mongo
```

However, the extension has been installed and phpinfo confirms it. I have also tested the extension with the code provided by php.net.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->demo->beers;

$result = $collection->insertOne( [ 'name' => 'Hinterland', 'brewery' => 'BrewDog' ] );

echo "Inserted with Object ID '{$result->getInsertedId()}'";
?>
```

This test code resides in the same folder as moadmin.php and the Vork Enterprise Framework has likewise been installed in that folder.

I have also confirmed mongo is running on the server and can be accessed via

```
mongo
```

and reports

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
```

I've also tried connecting with dbKoda but it reports

```
Error: All configured authentication methods failed
```

even though its URI is

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

Not sure where to go or what to try from here to get a working connection to mongo from my win10 machine. As I indicated the test code works in the browser on the win10 machine but not moadmin nor dbKoda.

Suggestions please?

Comment: You need to install via `composer` as well. Very few things should actually **only** depend on the `pecl` install. See [MongoDB PHP Library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) for instructions and usage. That's actually the place where the `MongoDB\Client` namespace is defined.

Comment: I did that as well at least for the test code above. Are you suggesting I have to do that separately for moadmin and dbKoda each?